# Paperclip - attaching notes to images

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Am new to paperclip and have been experimenting with some examples on the web.

I have been following a tutorial on "Uploading multiple images with Rails and Paperclip" and have managed to create an album model which can have many photos.

Now i want the user to attach notes to each photo so that each time user upload a photo, he can also add a note next to that photo.

The first thing i did was to create an photonotes table and its model and then created the relationship between the 'Photo' model and the 'Photonote' model.

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :album

  has_many :photonotes, :dependent => :destroy
  #accepts_nested_attributes_for :photonotes  

  def photonote_attributes=(photonote_attributes)
    photonote_attributes.each do |attributes|
    photonotes.build(attributes)
    end
 end

  has_attached_file :data,
  :styles => {
    :thumb => "50x50#",
    :large => "640x480#"
  }

  validates_attachment_presence :data
  validates_attachment_content_type :data, 
  :content_type => ['image/jpeg', 'image/pjpeg', 
                                   'image/jpg', 'image/png']
end
```

I included a fields_for section in my '_photo.html.erb' partial to allow user to add a note to the photo.

--- albums controller
     def new
      @album = Album.new
      1.upto(3) { photo = @album.photos.build
                  photo.photonotes.build }
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html # new.html.erb
        format.xml  { render :xml => @album }
      end
     end

Everytime i create an album and add an image with a note, i get the following error message:
'Something has gone wrong!'...

Any suggestion is most welcomed. Being new to RoR, sorry if this question is kind of stupid :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<% fields_for "album[photo_attributes][]", photo do |p| %>
  <p>
    <%= p.label :Photo %><br />
    <%= p.file_field :data, :index => nil %>


<% fields_for "photo[photonote_attributes][]", photonote do |builder| %>
<%= builder.text_field :note %>
<% end %>

  </p>
<% end %>
```

Above is the code i used but it's not working..

edit

I think it should be something like this:

```
<% fields_for "album[photo_attributes][photonote_attributes][]", photonote do |builder| %>
<%= builder.text_field :note %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I edited in something you can try out. You're double nesting so the photo note params need to be inside the photo params, inside the album params.

Comment: thanks a lot mark, i tried using accepts_nested_attributes as u suggested and it's working great :) that's true it does make things easier, thank u so much

Answer (score 2):

You're nearly there with the accepts_nested_attributes_for. Off the top of my head your form should look something like this.

```
= form_for @photo, :url => album_path(@album), :html => { :multipart => true } do |f|   
  = f.file_field :photo
  = f.fields_for :photonotes, @album.photo_notes.build do |f_pn|
    = f_pn.text_area :whatever_your_note_field_is_called
```

By the way, will a user be requiring to upload many notes per photo? If not then do away with the one to many and add the field to the photo itself.

Comment: hi mark thanks for the reply..please note that my album does not use nested attributes for photos and this is where am stuck :(

Comment: Sorry, I didn't finish my sentence: I don't know what tutorial you're following but suspect it was for an older version of rails from before accepts_nested_attributes existed. Really I don't see why you wouldn't use it as it's really easy.

Comment: you are right, i will try using accepts_nested attributes..Thanks a lot for the suggestion :)